# SimpleDateFormat Parse a time string with current date

Tags: java, android, date

I receive a time string, for example `14:26:16`, which refers to today.
My requirement is to find the difference between the current time and the given time.

SimpleDateFormat parses the string without an exception, but instead of getting `25/10/2015 14:26:16` I get `01/01/1970 14:26:16`. As simple as it sounds, I haven't figured out a simple way to parse it with the correct date.

My current code:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date currentTime = new Date(); //25/10/2015
Date arrivalTime = formatter.parse(eta); //01/01/1970
final long difference = arrivalTime.getTime() - currentTime.getTime();
```

Comment: What Java version are you working with? The old `Date` and related classes are pretty much obsolete by now and if you're writing new code, you should be using Java 8 java.time, or in older Java, JodaTime.

Comment: I didn't mention that I'm developing to Android. Does it still apply? I'm using JRE 1.8.0_45 but I failed to import the package's classes.

Comment: You can't use Java 8 with Android, It only supports up to Java 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for Java 7 and will work with Android.

```
/**
 *  Android utility to get the elapsed milliseconds between a String timestamp (in the future) and the current time
 * @param timeStamp Accepts a String in the form of HH:mm:ss
 * @return Elapsed time in milliseconds
 * @throws ParseException
 */
public static long timeDiff(String timeStamp) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Date arrivalTime = formatter.parse(timeStamp);

    Calendar arrivalCal= Calendar.getInstance();
    arrivalCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, arrivalTime.getHours());
    arrivalCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, arrivalTime.getMinutes());
    arrivalCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, arrivalTime.getSeconds());
    arrivalCal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    return arrivalCal.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

To address the comment above about Joda-time, Joda is a great time utility library but it'll add a lot of overhead to your project. If you repeatedly need to write time conversion methods then you should probably switch to Joda, but for just one method it does not warrant the added cost to your project.

Comment: I was a little concerned about using these deprecated methods, but thanks to the discussion here I found out that it's probably the right solution for my project (where the date manipulation part is indeed minor). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using `LocalTime`
Something like this

```
LocalTime arrivalTime = LocalTime.parse(eta, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME);
LocalTime currentTime = LocalTime.now();
final long difference = arrivalTime.getLong(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_DAY) - currentTime.getLong(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_DAY);
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#minus-long-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit- could make things better IMHO

Comment: @RC. yeah, that looks better, but I just adapted existed code to new date api:)

Comment: I think using `Duration.between(currentTime,arrivalTime).toMillis()` would be better.

Comment: Since I'm developing to Andriod, I'm limited to Java 7. Any ideas how to solve it without the new java.time package?

Comment: @NeriaNachum Java8 date api provides similar to JodaTime api, so you can use JodaTime. Or just set day month and year of the `Date` object that you create